# std::cin limitations can't input LPCSTR

Tags: c++

I have a program in which one of the variables types is a LPCSTR and the user needs to input that however std::cin can't give LPCSTR a value here is  some code

```
LPCSTR windowName;
std::cin >> windowName;
```

Comment: That's an uninitialised pointer. Using it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Fureeish `LPCSTR` is an alias defined in `<Windows.h>`, to `const char *`

Answer (score 11):

The type `LPCSTR` is just a pointer, it's an alias for `const char *`.

So you have two problems with the statement

```
std::cin >> windowName;
```

The first is that you use an *uninitialized pointer* as the destination. The second is that the pointer (once properly initialized) points to a *constant* memory area, that you can't write to or change.

The compiler should complain about the second issue (pointer to constant memory), while an uninitialized pointer will lead to undefined behavior (and possible crashes) at run-time.

---

The easiest solution is to use a `std::string` for the string, and when you need an `LPCSTR` simply use the `c_str()` member function.

Comment: `The second is that the pointer (once properly initialized) points to a constant memory area` More precisely, the pointer *may* point to a constant memory area. But whether it does or not, the compiler will not allow modification through the const pointer.